# Solve $(x^2+1)^2=4x(1-x^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $(x^2+1)^2=4x(1-x^2)$. I haven't tried anything real yet, except to expand. I know it is easy but I don't have any idea for the moment. So please help!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Try to show that the equation is equivalent to $(x^2+2x-1)^2=0$.